# Merge incompatible types. ex: type '{}' is not assignable to type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

## How do I merge the types

```
type TheseTypes = typeof TouchableNativeFeedback &
    typeof TouchableWithoutFeedback &
    typeof TouchableHighlight &
    typeof TouchableOpacity;

const Button: React.FC<CustomProps> = (props) => {

  const ButtonInstance: TheseTypes =
    props.highlight
      ? TouchableHighlight
      : props.nativeFeedback
      ? TouchableNativeFeedback
      : props.withoutFeedback
      ? TouchableWithoutFeedback
      : TouchableOpacity;

  return (
    <ButtonInstance
      {...props}
      activeOpacity={props.opacity}>
      {props.children}
    </ButtonInstance>
  );
};
```

I already tried using both union, intersection, `Partial<T>`, a custom `type Subtract<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof K>>`

### Case 0 - Props incomplete.

`activeOpacity`from Touchable Highlight/Opacity is not recognized.

#### Result on type inference (without assigning a type to RenderButton)

`(JSX attribute) activeOpacity: number
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<TouchableNativeFeedbackProps>): TouchableWithoutFeedback | TouchableNativeFeedback', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: ReactNode; disabled: any; activeOpacity: number; style: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableWithoutFeedback | TouchableNativeFeedback> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.
      Property 'activeOpacity' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableWithoutFeedback | TouchableNativeFeedback> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: TouchableNativeFeedbackProps, context?: any): TouchableWithoutFeedback | TouchableNativeFeedback', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: ReactNode; disabled: any; activeOpacity: number; style: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableWithoutFeedback | TouchableNativeFeedback> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.
      Property 'activeOpacity' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableWithoutFeedback | TouchableNativeFeedback> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.ts(2769)`

#### Result on `|`

Same as above.

### Case 1 - Props OK, Error line 5

On declaring `const RenderButton`, I receive these errors below, but VSCode Intellisense recommends the right props.

#### Result on `&`

`Type 'TouchableWithoutFeedback' is missing the following properties from type 'TouchableHighlight': measure, measureInWindow, measureLayout, setNativeProps, and 2 more.ts(2322)`

#### Result on `Partial<>&`

`Types of property 'prototype' are incompatible.
        Type 'TouchableWithoutFeedback' is missing the following properties from type 'TouchableHighlight': measure, measureInWindow, measureLayout, setNativeProps, and 2 more.ts(2322)`

#### Result on `Partial<>|`

`Type 'typeof TouchableNativeFeedback' is not assignable to type 'Partial<typeof TouchableWithoutFeedback> | Partial<typeof TouchableHighlight> | Partial<TouchableNativeFeedback> | Partial<...>'.
    Type 'typeof TouchableNativeFeedback' is not assignable to type 'Partial<typeof TouchableOpacity>'.
      Types of property 'prototype' are incompatible.
        Type 'TouchableNativeFeedback' is missing the following properties from type 'TouchableOpacity': setOpacityTo, setTimeout, clearTimeout, setInterval, and 11 more.ts(2322)`

Comment: What is the goal you are trying to accomplish? Are you building a Button component for which you would like to be able to select the underlying `Touchable` type based on some props? 
Also: is `ButtonProps` imported from `react-native` or do you define it alongside the component? Where do `highlight`, `disabled`, `opacity` etc. come from?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to use the button component and just pass in what Touchable to use. No, it doesn't come from RN. The variables either comes from props or are defined inside. I omitted some parts of the code. I will edit this.

Comment: In that case, perhaps it would be worth the time to rephrase your question to indicate the core problem you wanted to solve (swapping those Touchable implementations to make a more reusable button). That way it would be more general and can help others with a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you explain in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164987/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-typeof-touchablenativefeedback-typeof-touch?noredirect=1#comment108281014_61164987), you'd like to be able to swap different implementations of Touchable inside your custom Button component.

This is an interesting problem. I will suggest a slightly different approach, where we do not have to try to combine / union the different Touchable types.

Instead, we will allow providing any component as our wrapper (this could be limited to Touchables, if you need), and the props will adjust based on that component type. Internally, you can then layout the Button the way you want, add icons, titles and so on, and add additional props for them.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

// this type is generic over some arbitrary element type and will 'extend' its props
type Props<T extends React.ElementType> = React.ComponentProps<T> & {
  Touchable?: T;
  title: string;
};

// this component is generic but you do not need to pass the generic parameter inside jsx (will be inferred from the Touchable prop)
const Button = <T extends React.ElementType>({
  Touchable = TouchableOpacity,
  title,
  ...props
}: Props<T>) => (
  <Touchable {...props}>
    <Text>{title}</Text>
  </Touchable>
);

// the component can then be used like so:
const ButtonOpacity = (
  <Button activeOpacity={0} onPress={() => {}} title="title" />
);

// here we have an error - property `activeOpacity` does not exist on this type
const ButtonWithoutFeedback = (
  <Button
    Touchable={TouchableWithoutFeedback}
    activeOpacity={10}
    onPress={() => {}}
    title="title"
  />
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a really neat solution. I liked that the props vary depending on the value. But I found if I don't pass the prop `Touchable={any_value_here}` (relying on default value) I don't get the IntelliSense either for title or Touchable. This is not a problem at all, just learning what more I can do with TS.